# Can I redefine String#length?

Tags: string, groovy

I'd like to re-implement a method of a Java class. For example, for `"hi".length()` to return `4`. (How) Can I do that?

I know using SomeClass.metaClass I can get a reference to an existing method and define new (or overriding) method, but I can't seem to be able to do that for existing Java methods.

Comment: That would be incorrect behavior. You might be able to use a `pad()` method which would extend your string to a given max length. Then you could call length on that string.

Comment: What do you like to achieve with that? You'd break a lot of code this way.

Comment: Why? How many things are you liable to break by doing this? I can make 2 + 2 = 5, but may not really be the best solution. Perhaps you want to simply adjust the returned value in a few special situations?

Comment: It's just for example's sake.

Comment: He's asking whether or not he can change the implementation of methods in existing classes. You can do this in e.g. Ruby.

Comment: @IttayD: can you give an example that would actually make a valuable addition and still demonstrates your intention?

Comment: It just reminds me of when I redefined 'eval' in LISP, just to confuse my teacher when he tried to understand why (+ 4 1) returned 3 on my console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it could be possible by [abusing](http://naleid.com/blog/2009/06/01/groovy-metaclass-overriding-a-method-whilst-using-the-old-implementation/) String [metaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses). But the attempt I've done so far in groovy console didn't led to the expected result :

```
def oldLength = String.metaClass.length
String.metaClass.length = { ->
    return oldLength+10;
}

println "hi".length()
```

outputs the sad `2`

I think you could take a look at [Proxy MetaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+the+Proxy+Meta+Class) or [Delegating metaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+the+Delegating+Meta+Class).

Comment: I think the problem is related to this issue: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3493

Comment: Seems so, this works: String.metaClass.invokeMethod = { String methodName, args ->
    println("hi")
}

"hi".length() // prints "hi"

Comment: Why has this answer been accepted when by the author's own admission it doesn't actually work?

Comment: Mayube did I provide enough information to let it conclude by himself. But, as you state, I don't give the full answer here (however his comment seems to indicate he find the answer).

Comment: i accepted because it was the closest to an answer at the time (i did know about this approach)

Answer (score 4):

Using Groovy, you can replace any method (even those of final classes) with your own implementation. Method replacement in Groovy uses the meta-object protocol, not inheritance.

Here's the example you requested, i.e. how to make `String.length()` always return 4

```
// Redefine the method
String.metaClass.invokeMethod = { name, args ->

    def metaMethod = delegate.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
    def result = metaMethod.invoke(delegate, args)

    name == 'length' ? 4 : result
}

// Test it
assert "i_do_not_have_4_chars".length() == 4
```

Comment: note to others that may wonder why this wasn't accepted as an answer: it was submitted after i commented that this is the solution in the answer above

Comment: You can unaccept the other answer and accept this one if you feel it's better. Just click the green check mark to unaccept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you did redefine it, it would only work in Groovy code. Groovy can't change the way Java code executes.

In Groovy, `"hi".length()` is roughly equivalent to this Java:

```
stringMetaClass.invokeMethod("hi","length");
```

Because Groovy doesn't actually call length directly, metaClass tricks work in Groovy code. But Java doesn't know about MetaClasses, so there is no way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is very old I like to point out another way (at least for newer Groovy versions) .
The `length()` method in `java.lang.String` is implemented from `java.lang.CharSequence` interface. In order to reimplement the method using the String-metaClass you need to "override" the method in the metaClass of the interface first.

```
CharSequence.metaClass.length = { -> -1}
String.metaClass.length = { -> 4 }
assert "i_do_not_have_4_chars".length() == 4
```

The solution using `String.metaClass.invokeMethod` changes the behaviour of all String-methods and is problematic. For instance, simply invoking `"asdf".size()` leads to an exception on my setup.